# Prove $\frac{2|z-2w-3-6i|+3|w+2+4i|}{|2z-w|}\lt1$

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing

Deduce whether the statement is true or false.

(*): There exists some $z,w\in \Bbb C$ such that $w\neq2z$ and $\frac{2|z-2w-3-6i|+3|w+2+4i|}{|2z-w|}\lt1$.

I have no idea how I should start. Should I pick any value for $z,w$ to prove or set them as $a+bi, c+di$?

Is this related to Triangle Inequality? but I am not sure how to apply it in complex plane.

p.s. In this semester, I've learnt Triangle Inequality, Bernoulli's Inequality, Weierstrass' Inequality, Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality and AM-GM Inequality. Only these inequality are allowed to use.

Many thanks.

Comment: Note that $2z-w = 2 (z-2w-3-6i)+3(w+2+4i)$.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for the reminder!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: use the triangle inequality to show that
$$|\hbox{numerator}|\ge|\hbox{denominator}|\ .$$